# Is it good to fix issues in library files and use them in our project

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material

I encountered an issue in angular-material.js Version 1.1.9, I was able to fix the issue in the library file. Is it okay to use my fix in my project without checking in my fix in AngularJS Material's GitHub repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would certainly be a better approach to file a Pull Request with the library project. Why?

- It will make you a better human being with glowing, wonderfully clear skin: You already have a bugfix, so why not share it?
- If you don't get it into the library, with the next update, you will lose your bugfix and will end up monkey-patching it with every new release.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I currently don't know the process of setting up the base for open source project so that's why I was waiting. Do you have any link describing how to setup any open source library project?

Comment: Normally, open source projects have some page describing how you can contribute. I'd suggest you go to the project site and look for that.